# Multiple config files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

.net C# visual studio

In our application we are using a single config file that has all the entries to our application
specific.

Now for release to production I need to add some extra entries to config file which should be just release
specific and not needed in development.

If it was just connection strings I could have added

```
 `<connectionStrings configSource="Configuration\ConnectionStrings.config">
 </connectionStrings>`
```

But I have some other entries like for example:

```
`<system.web>
    <authorization /> 
    <machineKey validationKey=""/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
     <modules>    
     </modules>
</system.webServer>`
```

and some more.

So how can I configure my application to use one config file for dev and separate for production.

Thanks

Comment: Most often there at least some minor differences between your Development and production config files. It is not unusual to have Keep two separate versions of the Config files. Once You have deployed your App once to the production environment with the correct (web).config file, you could simply deploy later releases without replacing the config file and make edits as needed directly on the file.

Comment: You can try to use [XDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) or [XSLT](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp) transformations. This transformations can transform your, for example, dev's config to production's config